# How to get the hash of the Fulfill Random Words transaction (callback) that gets mined after calling the Chainlink's VRF?

Tags: transactions, events, chainlink, hash, chainlink-vrf

I have the hash of the transaction that called Chainlink's VRF but I need to get the hash of the callback transaction that gets executed after the `RandomWordsRequested` event is fulfilled.

How do I do that? Is there a way of getting that information?

I need this because an event that I want to track gets emitted in my smart contract after that callback is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it if you navigate to the History (Recent fulfillments) tab of your VRF subscription at https://vrf.chain.link.

Also, you can monitor the `VRFCoordinatorV2` contract itself for `fulfillRandomWords` function calls.

[image: vrf]